# primefaces autoComplete dropdown button disabled bug

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

Here is the xhtml code for my autocomplete :

```
<p:column styleClass="col-quarter">
    <p:autoComplete dropdown="false"
            id="field"
            value="#{managedbean.valueToAssign}"
            completeMethod="#{managedbean.completeValue}"
            maxResults="7">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="Next_field" />
        <f:ajax event="itemSelect" render="Next_field" />
    </p:autoComplete>
</p:column>
```

Here's what I don't get : 
[image: Capture]

When I hover over that zone at the right of the field, the button is active. even if it's invisible. I want the field to be the same width than the next one, but the presence of the button prevents it.

I also tried without the `dropdown="false"` attribute but I still get the same result

**EDIT : I managed to get the same width for both input, but the button is still active even if invisible.**

Comment: Known issue in PrimeFaces 0.1...Tried without any theming or custom css?

Comment: we don't use any theme and I can't change the CSS. I think i'm just going to bear with it.

Comment: Ok... weird that you can't change the css and I don't see this behaviour in the showcase. But good luck!